# How to input an integer tuple from user?

Tags: python

Presently I am doing this

```
print 'Enter source'
source = tuple(sys.stdin.readline())

print 'Enter target'
target = tuple(sys.stdin.readline())
```

but source and target become string tuples in this case with a \n at the end

Comment: (n, m) = tuple(map(int, input().split(" ")))

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
tuple(int(x.strip()) for x in raw_input().split(','))
```

Comment: How should the user give input now.
I tried 4,0...it doesn't work

Comment: I get the output-
Enter source
0,4
Enter target
3,2
('0', '4')
('3', '2')

Comment: Ah, I modified my answer slightly after. Compare what you have with what I wrote.

Comment: `sys.stdin.readline()` does have the advantage of working across python2 and python3. In python3 `raw_input` is renamed to `input`

Answer (score 7):

Turns out that `int` does a pretty good job of stripping whitespace, so there is no need to use `strip`

```
tuple(map(int,raw_input().split(',')))
```

For example:

```
>>> tuple(map(int,"3,4".split(',')))
(3, 4)
>>> tuple(map(int," 1 , 2 ".split(',')))
(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still want the user to be prompted twice etc.

```
print 'Enter source'
source = sys.stdin.readline().strip()  #strip removes the \n

print 'Enter target'
target = sys.stdin.readline().strip()

myTuple = tuple([int(source), int(target)])
```

This is probably less pythonic, but more didactic...

Comment: source and target are themselves tuples. We can use int() on tuples.

Comment: Sorry, the desired output is unclear. At any rate, the string.strip() and the int() should allow you to get exactly what you need, be it two tuples of a single integer each, or one tuple with the source and target values.

Answer (score 0):

```
t= tuple([eval(x) for x in input("enter the values: ").split(',')])
```