# Python 2.7 taking input from user for two separate variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

```
getMin, getMax = int(input("Enter a range (min,max): "));
```

Above is the code I am trying to implement but it gives me an error saying...

```
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'
```

Basically, I have tried entering `.split(,)` after the input statement but I get the same error. When a user enters 1,10 as an input I want `getMin = 1` and `getMax = 10`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to input an integer tuple from user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233917/how-to-input-an-integer-tuple-from-user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `input`  function (see [doc here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input)) will try to evaluate the provided input. For example, if you feed  it with your name *AMcCauley13* it will look for a variable named so.
Feeding it with values like `1,10` will evaluate in a tuple `(1,10)`, which will break the `int()` function that expects a string.

Try with the simpler

```
getMin = int(raw_input("min range: "))
getMax = int(raw_input("max range: "))
```

or combining `split` and `map` as [balki suggested in the meanwhile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46437024/1029516)

Comment: thank you! I had it done this way initially but did not know if my professor would accept it done that way.

Comment: How about don't use `input` at all, so you don't have to deal with strings like `__import__('os').system('cat /etc/passwd')`.

Comment: that's a good point. Fixing it to avoid misleading others that may use it for something more than an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on Python 2, you should be using `raw_input` instead of `input`.  Try something like this:

```
from ast import literal_eval

prompt = "Enter a range (min,max): "
getMin = getMax = None

while {type(getMin), type(getMax)} != {int}:
    try:
        getMin, getMax = literal_eval(raw_input(prompt))
    except (ValueError, TypeError, SyntaxError):
        pass  # ask again...
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, cleaner approach assuming you want the input to be comma separated

```
>>> prompt = "Enter a range (min,max): "
>>> while True:
...     try:
...             getMin, getMax = map(int, raw_input(prompt).split(','))
...             break
...     except (ValueError, TypeError):
...             pass
... 
Enter a range (min,max): skfj slfjd
Enter a range (min,max): 232,23123,213
Enter a range (min,max): 12, 432
>>> getMin
12
>>> getMax
432
```