# invalid literal for int() with base 10 : '(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)'

Tags: python

```
tuple1 = int(input())
list1 = list()
for i in tuple1:
    if tuple1[i-1] % 2 == 0:
        list1.append(tuple1[i-1])
tuple2 = tuple(list1)
print(tuple2)
```

I'm getting error as

> invalid literal for int() with base 10 : '(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)'

Comment: `int('(1,2,3,4)')` not a valid way to get tuple.

Comment: Also, `i` is an element of `tuple1`, not an index. What do you want `tuple2` to *be* on an input of `(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to input an integer tuple from user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233917/how-to-input-an-integer-tuple-from-user)

Answer (score 2):

you could use `literal_eval` from the `ast` module to try and convert the input to a `tuple`, e.g.

```
from ast import literal_eval

s = '(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)' # your input...
t = literal_eval(s)

print(t, type(t))
# (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) <class 'tuple'>
```

Answer (score -2):

use `range()` in `input()`

```
tuple1 = range(int(input()))
```

You can't make iteration in a number, when you use the `range()` method, you can iterate over it.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right issue? The problem is on line 1 of the code in the question.

Comment: ...see  Ch3steR's comment below the question

Comment: This answer is even worse. You can't fix `int(input())`, with `(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)` typed in as the input, by wrapping it in `range()`. Please try actually _running_ the code you recommend.